# How can I use jquery .grep() to find an object then update it?

Tags: jquery, arrays

Im doing a simple algorithm which needs to get an object from a jquery key/value array, do some updates on it then replace the original object within the array with the updated object. How do I go about doing this?

What I have so far is the fetching of the object using grep:

```
 var country = $.grep(contentArray, function (e) { return e.key == countrykey; });

 country.value = 'Malta';

 //Need to replace old 'country' object in contentArray
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

grep return an array

```
var country = $.grep(contentArray, function (e) { return e.key == countrykey; });
if(country && country.length == 1)
 country[0].value = 'Malta';
```

Comment: I understand that it works but why it works I dont understand yet. I mean why the third line is changing the original contentArray? ... I think this has something to do with scope but couldnt visualise it.